# Count occurrence in table PHP echo

Tags: php, html, mysql

I’m new to PHP and MySQL & while there are a bunch of examples on this throughout StackOverflow, but none of them apply very well to my situation.

So, I have a table (named **votes**) that looks like this:

```
 student_name | student_id | teacher
----------------------------------------
Joe           | 991991991  | Mr. Smith
Sally         | 717356152  | Ms. Lozano
Benny         | 383717747  | Mr. Johnson
Jim           | 191918918  | Mr. Smith
John          | 182783718  | Mr. Smith
Alfred        | 374878372  | Mr. Johnson
```

I want an `HTML`/`PHP` page to output this in one of my DIVs, automatically looping through all options for teacher and counting how many times each teacher occurs. I want it to automatically count new teachers as they are added, so that I do not have to change the code afterwords.

```
Mr. Smith: 3
Mr. Johnson: 2
Ms. Lozano: 1
```

It does not need to be in any order, i shouldn't have put them from least to greatest.

I've tried to do something like

```
<?php SELECT teacher, SUM(1) FROM votes GROUP BY teacher ?>
```

or

```
SELECT teacher, count(teacher) 
  FROM votes 
 GROUP by teacher
```

But they don't work and give me an error of `"syntax error, unexpected 'teacher' (T_STRING)"`
I could just be implementing them wrong. Do they just occur in their own , or do they need a their own connection or their own while statement or something before?

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** Here is my full body code with my connection...

```
$connection = mysql_connect($serverName, $userName, $password) or die('Unable to connect to Database host' . mysql_error());
$dbselect = mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection) or die("Unable to select database:$dbname" . mysql_error());
?>
</head>
    <body>
    <div align="center">
    <form method="post" action="vote_1.php">
    <h1>Counted Vote Totals</h1>
    <h4>(these values are current)</h4>
    <h2>Votes by Cantidate</h2>
    <?php SELECT teacher, count(teacher) 
  FROM votes 
 GROUP by teacher ?>
</br></br></br>
</form>
</body>
```

I did not include my head because of passwords, etc.

Comment: You can't do `<?php SELECT teacher, SUM(1) FROM votes GROUP BY teacher ?>` first of all, if that's the actual code you're attempting to run. You first need to connect to DB, then query.

Comment: You can't put SQL statements directly into PHP, you have to use a database API. The ones to learn are PDO and mysqli, they're in the PHP documentation.

Comment: As per your edit; you can't do it that way. If it were that easy, I for one would love it ;-)

Comment: OK, now that you've updated your question, what you're missing is that you have to call `mysql_query()` to perform the query, than call `mysql_fetch_assoc()` to get the rows from the results. There are many PHP+MySQL tutorials you can read that show how to do this.

Comment: Ok, thanks! ill look and see what I can find. I didn't even know what to look for lol

Comment: @Barmar OP should use [`mysqli_*`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) because `mysql_*` is [deprecated as of PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php).

Comment: Yes, he should, and I said so in my first comment. But since he's not, I then told him how he should write the code using the API he's already started using.

Comment: Hah, I read right over that and just saw your second comment referencing the `mysql_*` functions. My bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly is this here:

```
<?php SELECT teacher, count(teacher) 
  FROM votes 
 GROUP by teacher ?>
```

As far as PHP is concerned, that is plain text & not a MySQL query. Quickly off the top of my head, this should work to show you the basic concept of how PHP & MySQL work with each other. Note the `mysql_query`.

```
$connection = mysql_connect($serverName, $userName, $password) or die('Unable to connect to Database host' . mysql_error());
$dbselect = mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection) or die("Unable to select database:$dbname" . mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("SELECT teacher, count(teacher) as teacher_count FROM votes GROUP by teacher;");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['teacher'];
    echo $row['teacher_count'];
}
```

That said, `mysql_*` prefixed PHP functions are depreciated. Meaning they will no longer work in upcoming version of PHP.  So here is a version of your code using `mysqli_*` instead [using examples from the official PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

```
$link = mysqli_connect($serverName, $userName, $password, $dbname);

// Check the connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

// Select queries return a resultset
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT teacher, count(teacher) as teacher_count FROM votes GROUP by teacher;")) {
    // This is optional. Feel free to comment out this line.
    printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", mysqli_num_rows($result));

    // Cycle through results
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
        echo $row['teacher'];
        echo $row['teacher_count'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Haha I have no idea, I saw on another forum that someone suggested it to someone else for a similar purpose... I just threw it in to hope it might produce something. It must have been for a completely different environment or something

Comment: OP should use [`mysqli_*`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) because `mysql_*` is [deprecated as of PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php).